# Have text in a TextBlock appear one letter at a time as if it was typed xaml, UWP

Tags: c#, xaml

Is there a way in UWP (C#/XAML) to have letters in a TextBlock appear one letter at a time as if you were watching it being typed? Like that old annoying transition in PowerPoint? It's for long strings of text so ideally I can control the speed. I'd be ok with one word showing at a time if this isn't possible. Thanks!

Comment: I can do a transition that makes the whole textblock appear at once, but not individual characters

Comment: Show code then. Don't expect others to solve the whole problem. This can be easily solved either by storyboard animations or programmatically using a background thread.